Does this function in $3$b$1$b has a name?
I was watching this video from $3$Blue$1$Brown channel, at minute 21:00 he introduced the following function:
$$
\chi(n)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n=2k \\
1 & \text{if } n=4k+1\\
-1 & \text{if } n=4k+3
\end{cases}
$$
which gave a beautiful solution to the problem. I wonder if this function has a name or if it is a special case of another function. Or maybe if there are some nice properties about it. He already mentioned that it is multiplicative.
I have already found out that if $n =  2^\gamma \times p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_l^{\alpha_l} \times q_1^{\beta_1}q_2^{\beta_2}\ldots q_\ell^{\beta_\ell}$ where $p_i$ are the primes of form $4k+1$ and $q_i$ are those of form $4k+3$, then
$$\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)=\begin{cases}
\prod_{i=1}^{l}(1+\alpha_i) & \text{if $\beta_i$ are even} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Any further ideas?

See Dirichlet character modulo $4$, also in wikipedia.

Its $\chi(n)$ (i.e, Chi(n)) in Hardy and Wright (see OEIS Entry A101455) where $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}=\beta(s),,\quad\Re(s)\ge 1$$ corresponds to the Dirichlet beta function.

By the way, you've rediscovered some a classical identity related to the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two squares—see for example Section 3.6 of Niven/Zuckerman/Montgomery's An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers (5th ed.).

Some more properties of $χ$:

Quadratic Characters and Kronecker Symbol:

It is a quadratic character related to the  Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)$.In particular
$$χ(n)=\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)$$

Used to construct L-functions :

L-functions are series of the form
$$L(s,χ)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{χ(n)}{n^s}$$

Orthogonality Relations:

The characters
$χ$ modulo
$m$ satisfy orthogonality relations, which are useful in various proofs and identities in number theory. For instance, if
$χ$ is a non-principal character modulo
$m$, then:
$$\sum^m_{n=1}χ(n)=0$$
And of course the two you already mentioned and I could assume many more.

Further Investigations:
1. Exploring Connections to Modular Forms:
Characters like $χ(n)$ often appear in the coefficients of modular forms. Studying these connections can reveal "interesting" properties of number theory.
2.  Generalizations to Other Moduli:
One might consider generalizations of
$χ(n)$ to other moduli and study their properties and applications.
3.  Combinatorial Identities:
Investigating sums and identities involving
$χ(n)$ can lead to interesting combinatorial insights and may reveal further structure in arithmetic functions.
4. Automorphic Forms:
Characters similar to
$χ(n)$ are used in the theory of automorphic forms, which generalize modular forms and have connections to representation theory and Langlands programs.

the function
$χ(n)$ you is a special case of a more general framework of multiplicative characters in number theory. Its properties and applications are rich and far-reaching, connecting to various fundamental aspects of mathematics.

Aside from the links I already provided , in the ones posted bellow you can find many interesting articles roughly revolving around $χ$. Articles I've read on JSTOR or arXiv  contain in-depth studies on specific properties and applications of multiplicative characters and related functions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue
http://www.numbertheory.org/ntw/search.html
https://arxiv.org/archive/math.NT
